# How to get windows form saveFileDialog directory

Tags: c#, winforms

I would like to save my image to a folder selected by the user. I know I could use stream out. But it seems easier to just get the path the user selects from the save file dialog provided by windows and then use that path in the save function from the Image class.

```
Image img1;
String path;
...

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SaveFileDialog saveFileDialog1 = new SaveFileDialog();

    // Directory to open when saving files
    saveFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = path;
    // Sets the title of your dialog box
    saveFileDialog1.Title = "Save";
    // Sets the file type to filter out
    saveFileDialog1.Filter = "png files (*.png)|*.png|All files (*.*)|*.*";
    saveFileDialog1.FilterIndex = 2;
    //Destroys file when done if set to false
    saveFileDialog1.RestoreDirectory = true; 

    if (saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        try
        {
            img1.Save(HERE);             
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error: Could not save file too disk. " + ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

I denoted the place the string directory path would go with "HERE."

Comment: have you looked at the docs for `SaveFileDialog`?

Comment: Sometimes [Google](https://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome-psyapi2&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8&q=savefiledialog%20selected%20path) can be a great of help.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the following: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.filedialog.filename(v=vs.110).aspx

Particularly 'saveFileDialog1.FileName'